# Consume a web service C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm building a web service, and it uses an external web services (example http://www.webservicex.com/stockquote.asmx?WSDL) , how do I consume the external web service inside the web service im building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have stated, add a web reference to your project.

This will give you a namespace that you can use in your project.  Here is a snippet from one of my Utility classes.

```
using System;
//...there's more
using System.Text;
using WSDebug.patweb; //web reference to WSDL

namespace WSDebug
{
    class Utils
    {
        private static R12_WebService ws = new R12_WebService();
```

patweb is the name of my web reference.  The web reference itself contains many classes.  The R12_WebService class is the one that contains the web service methods outlined in the WSDL.  The other classes and delegates are all eventargs and eventhandlers for our asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Service Reference to the external Web Service inside your Web Service Project.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a web reference in your calling service by right clicking the project and adding a web reference to the service you wish to consume.

You can keep chaining services like this for instance Service A -> B -> C

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a Web Reference to the project?

Answer (score 0):

By adding a Web Reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Right-Click on the project and "Add Web Reference". Point to the location (url) the service is hosted.